# Community users and internal salesforce role hierarchy

Tags: community

Can we assign community users to internal sales force role hierarchy

when i go from setup->manage users->roles
and try to add users to a specific roles.i cannot find community users here.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The full sharing model, including role-based sharing, is only accessible to Partner Community licenses. Customer Communities licenses come with Sharing Sets and in Winter '14 Sharing Groups will enable the sharing of records to basically a manually maintained group of either internal or external users.